# Difference between logloss in sklearn and BCEloss in Pytorch?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

Looking at the documentation for logloss in Sklearn and BCEloss in Pytorch, these should be the same, i.e. just the normal log loss with weights applied. However, they behave differently - both with and without weights applied. Can anyone explain it to me? I could not find the source code for BCEloss (which refers to binary_cross_entropy internally).

```
input = torch.randn((3, 1), requires_grad=True)
target = torch.ones((3, 1), requires_grad=False)
w = torch.randn((3, 1), requires_grad=False)

# ----- With weights
w = F.sigmoid(w)
criterion_test = nn.BCELoss(weight=w)
print(criterion_test(input=F.sigmoid(input), target=F.sigmoid(target)))
print(log_loss(y_true=target.detach().numpy(), 
               y_pred=F.sigmoid(input).detach().numpy(), sample_weight=w.detach().numpy().reshape(-1), labels=np.array([0.,1.])))
print("")
print("")
# ----- Without weights
criterion_test = nn.BCELoss()
print(criterion_test(input=F.sigmoid(input),target=F.sigmoid(target)))
print(log_loss(y_true=target.detach().numpy(), 
               y_pred=F.sigmoid(input).detach().numpy(), labels=np.array([0.,1.])))
```

Comment: @BramVanroy It is right there. See criterion_test = nn.BCELoss(weight=w) and the same with logloss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out. It turns out that BCELoss and log_loss behaves differently *when the weights sum up to more than the dimension of the input array*. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the computation without weights, using [`BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bcewithlogitsloss) you get the same result as for [`sklearn.metrics.log_loss`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html#sklearn.metrics.log_loss):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
import numpy as np

input = torch.randn((3, 1), requires_grad=True)
target = torch.ones((3, 1), requires_grad=False)

# ----- Without weights
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
criterion(input, target)
print('{:.6f}'.format(criterion(input, target)))
print('{:.6f}'.format((log_loss(y_true=target.detach().numpy(),
                                y_pred=torch.sigmoid(input).detach().numpy(),
                                labels=np.array([0.,1.])))))
```

Note that:

> This loss combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single
>   class. This version is more numerically stable than using a plain
>   Sigmoid followed by a BCELoss as, by combining the operations into one
>   layer, we take advantage of the log-sum-exp trick for numerical
>   stability.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Did not know that was more numerical stable. However, in the meantime I found out the BCELoss at least does not 'normalize' the weights internally wheras log_loss from Sklearn does.